# Error when downloading the glove_python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, glove

When I try to download the glove_python package by

`pip install glove_python`

I get the following error:

```
  Using cached glove_python-0.1.0.tar.gz (263 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\eweli\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\embeddingscode\lib\site-packages (from glove_python) (1.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\eweli\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\embeddingscode\lib\site-packages (from glove_python) (1.4.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: glove-python
  Building wheel for glove-python (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\eweli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\\glove-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\eweli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\\glove-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-fqc_1mwe'
       cwd: C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\glove-python\
  Complete output (60 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\glove
  copying glove\corpus.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\glove
  copying glove\glove.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\glove
  copying glove\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\glove
  running build_ext
  building 'glove.glove_cython' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\include -IC:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcglove/glove_cython.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove/glove_cython.obj -fopenmp -ffast-math
  cl : Wiersz polecenia warning D9002 : ignorowanie nieznanej opcji ,-fopenmp"
  cl : Wiersz polecenia warning D9002 : ignorowanie nieznanej opcji ,-ffast-math"
  glove_cython.c
  glove/glove_cython.c(1692): warning C4244: "=": konwersja z "Py_ssize_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/glove_cython.c(1701): warning C4244: "=": konwersja z "Py_ssize_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/glove_cython.c(2348): warning C4244: "=": konwersja z "Py_ssize_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/glove_cython.c(2357): warning C4244: "=": konwersja z "Py_ssize_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_glove_cython build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove/glove_cython.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\glove\glove_cython.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove\glove_cython.cp36-win_amd64.lib -fopenmp
  LINK : warning LNK4044: nierozpoznana opcja ,/fopenmp"; zignorowano
     Trwa tworzenie biblioteki build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove\glove_cython.cp36-win_amd64.lib i obiektu build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove\glove_cython.cp36-win_amd64.exp
  Trwa generowanie kodu
  Zakonczono generowanie kodu
  building 'glove.metrics.accuracy_cython' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove\metrics
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\include -IC:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcglove/metrics/accuracy_cython.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove/metrics/accuracy_cython.obj -fopenmp -ffast-math
  cl : Wiersz polecenia warning D9002 : ignorowanie nieznanej opcji ,-fopenmp"
  cl : Wiersz polecenia warning D9002 : ignorowanie nieznanej opcji ,-ffast-math"
  accuracy_cython.c
  glove/metrics/accuracy_cython.c(1569): warning C4244: "=": konwersja z "Py_ssize_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/metrics/accuracy_cython.c(1578): warning C4244: "=": konwersja z "Py_ssize_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/metrics/accuracy_cython.c(1587): warning C4244: "=": konwersja z "Py_ssize_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  creating C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\glove-python\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\glove\metrics
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_accuracy_cython build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove/metrics/accuracy_cython.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\glove\metrics\accuracy_cython.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove/metrics\accuracy_cython.cp36-win_amd64.lib -fopenmp
  LINK : warning LNK4044: nierozpoznana opcja ,/fopenmp"; zignorowano
     Trwa tworzenie biblioteki build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove/metrics\accuracy_cython.cp36-win_amd64.lib i obiektu build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove/metrics\accuracy_cython.cp36-win_amd64.exp
  Trwa generowanie kodu
  Zakonczono generowanie kodu
  building 'glove.corpus_cython' extension
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\include -IC:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpglove/corpus_cython.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove/corpus_cython.obj -fopenmp -ffast-math
  cl : Wiersz polecenia warning D9002 : ignorowanie nieznanej opcji ,-fopenmp"
  cl : Wiersz polecenia warning D9002 : ignorowanie nieznanej opcji ,-ffast-math"
  corpus_cython.cpp
  glove/corpus_cython.cpp(1796): warning C4267: "=": konwersja z "size_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2025): warning C4267: "argument": konwersja z "size_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2235): warning C4267: "=": konwersja z "size_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2310): warning C4267: "=": konwersja z "size_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3251): warning C4267: "=": konwersja z "size_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3403): warning C4244: "argument": konwersja z "double" do "float", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3431): warning C4244: "argument": konwersja z "double" do "float", mozliwa utrata danych
  glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3457): warning C4244: "argument": konwersja z "Py_ssize_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" stdc++.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_corpus_cython build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove/corpus_cython.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\glove\corpus_cython.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove\corpus_cython.cp36-win_amd64.lib -fopenmp -ffast-math
  LINK : warning LNK4044: nierozpoznana opcja ,/fopenmp"; zignorowano
  LINK : warning LNK4044: nierozpoznana opcja ,/ffast-math"; zignorowano
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: nie mozna otworzyc pliku wejsciowego ,stdc++.lib"
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for glove-python
  Running setup.py clean for glove-python
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\eweli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\\glove-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\eweli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\\glove-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\glove-python
  Complete output (6 lines):
  usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: setup.py --help-commands
     or: setup.py cmd --help

  error: option --all not recognized
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for glove-python
Failed to build glove-python
Installing collected packages: glove-python
    Running setup.py install for glove-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\eweli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\\glove-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\eweli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\\glove-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jr5q51hf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\Include\glove-python'
         cwd: C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\glove-python\
    Complete output (22 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'glove.corpus_cython' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\include -IC:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpglove/corpus_cython.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove/corpus_cython.obj -fopenmp -ffast-math
    cl : Wiersz polecenia warning D9002 : ignorowanie nieznanej opcji ,-fopenmp"
    cl : Wiersz polecenia warning D9002 : ignorowanie nieznanej opcji ,-ffast-math"
    corpus_cython.cpp
    glove/corpus_cython.cpp(1796): warning C4267: "=": konwersja z "size_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
    glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2025): warning C4267: "argument": konwersja z "size_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
    glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2235): warning C4267: "=": konwersja z "size_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
    glove/corpus_cython.cpp(2310): warning C4267: "=": konwersja z "size_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
    glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3251): warning C4267: "=": konwersja z "size_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
    glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3403): warning C4244: "argument": konwersja z "double" do "float", mozliwa utrata danych
    glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3431): warning C4244: "argument": konwersja z "double" do "float", mozliwa utrata danych
    glove/corpus_cython.cpp(3457): warning C4244: "argument": konwersja z "Py_ssize_t" do "int", mozliwa utrata danych
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" stdc++.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_corpus_cython build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove/corpus_cython.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\glove\corpus_cython.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\glove\corpus_cython.cp36-win_amd64.lib -fopenmp -ffast-math
    LINK : warning LNK4044: nierozpoznana opcja ,/fopenmp"; zignorowano
    LINK : warning LNK4044: nierozpoznana opcja ,/ffast-math"; zignorowano
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181: nie mozna otworzyc pliku wejsciowego ,stdc++.lib"
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\eweli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\\glove-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\eweli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8qqfg3a\\glove-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jr5q51hf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\eweli\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\EmbeddingsCode\Include\glove-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I found some answers online that claimed that the solution might be to use different python version. I tried using version 3.6.9, 3.6.10 and 3.7.7 and nothing solved the problem.

I also tried updating the setuptools package, which didn't help either.

The above error is with python version 3.6.9 and setuptools version 46.2.0

What is going wrong with the installation? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`pip install  glove-python-binary`